# Can explain me in the way I understand

Tags: sentence-meaning

the services performed by workers for wages as distinguished from those rendered by entrepreneurs for profits. What does it mean? Can explain me one by one?

Comment: If you have a source, that would be very preferable. Can you explain what you don't understand? Any depth is good.

Comment: I can't parse this into a sentence; I may be missing something, but if this is a fragment / excerpt from text, please provide the source or some context of the complete sentence. More details make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: [Please correct your grammar: Can you explain **to me** etc. Thank you. In two places.]

Answer (score 1):

As the comments make clear, the lack of context or any citations makes it difficult to figure out what is meant for **certain**. **PROBABLY**, what is meant is this.

The "entrepreneur" is usually defined as an entity that buys at definite prices in the expectation of selling for higher prices. If that expectation is met, the entrepreneur makes a "profit." If that expectation is not met, the entrepreneur suffers a loss. The "service" rendered by an entrepreneur is bearing risk related to future price.

The service rendered by a wage-earner is to provide a particular kind of labor for a particular length of time or for a certain piece of work. In return, a wage is paid, a predetermined amount of money.

So those are two differently named services that receive differently named remunerations. That is a simple distinction conceptually.

For example, an entrepreneur buys material and provides it to an artisan to make an object and agrees to pay an agreed-upon price when the object is delivered to the entrepreneur. The money paid to the artisan is a wage, a sum certain. If the entrepreneur can sell the object to a third party for more than the sum of the wages paid and cost of the material, that is the entrepreneur's profit. For some economists, the collective role of entrepreneurs is considered as central to economic development.

However, in many actual cases, the person who is the entrepreneur also does labor and usually must wait between the time when expenses are incurred and revenues received. So the entrepreneur is actually providing three services, bearing risk, waiting, and laboring. In such cases, it is very difficult to ascertain how to break down the remuneration received by the entrepreneur into the different categories.

Now all this may not be pertinent to the entire passage that you are reading. It depends the definitions used by the writer and the topic under discussion. But you have not told us any of that.

Comment: youre awesome ty